# Let $V,W$ be two vector spaces, $T \in L(V,W)$. If $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^p$ are linearly independent in $V$, is $\{T(v_i)\}_{i=1}^p$ so in $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Suppose $T : V \to W$ is one-to-one and linear. Show that linearly independent vectors in $V$ have linearly
independent images under $T$; that is, if $$\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$$
is linearly independent in $V$, then
$$\{T(v_1),T(v_2),··· ,T(v_n)\}$$
is linearly independent in $W$.

---

I know that since $T$ is one-to-one, the kernel of $T$ contains only the zero vector.

I am supposed to prove this by contradiction.

Let's assume that $$\{T(v_1),T(v_2),··· ,T(v_n)\}$$ is linearly dependent. Then there exists a scalar $c_1, c_2, ... , c_p$ such that $$c_1T(v_1) + c_2T(v_2) + ... + c_pT(v_p) = 0$$ where $c_1, c_2, ... , c_p$ are not all $0$.

Am I on the right track so far? How do I get to the point where I can reach my contradiction? Or is there a better way of proving the question?

Answer (score 4):

By the linearity of $T$, we have that

$$0 = \sum_{i=1}^p c_i T(v_i) = T \left( \sum_{i=1}^p c_i v_i \right)$$

Notice: $T$ is sending a vector, $\sum_i c_i v_i$, to $0$, and $\text{ker}(T) = \{0\}$. Hence, $\sum_i c_i v_i = 0$.

Consequently, our assumption of dependence leads to a choice of $c_i$, not all zero, for which $\sum c_i v_i = 0$, contradicting the independence of the original $\{v_i\}$.

Comment: Easier: $T \! \left( \sum_i c_iv_i \right) = 0$, so $\sum_i c_iv_i = 0$ because $\ker(T) = \{0\}$. No need of left inverses.

Comment: Ah, good point. Had a feeling there was a more obvious angle.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$c_1v_1+\cdots +c_nv_n =0$$  $$\Leftrightarrow T(c_1v_1+\cdots +c_nv_n)=T(0)\because T \text{is injective and well defined}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow T(c_1v_1+\cdots +c_nv_n)=0 \because T \text{is injective}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow c_1T(v_1)+\cdots +c_nT(v_n)=0 \because T \text{is a linear map}$$ But since $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n \}$ are linearly independent, the only way for the first equation to be true would be if $$c_1=\cdots =c_n =0.$$

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the first $\Leftrightarrow$ is valid because $T$ is one-to-one.